# How to copy a song from iPod Library to app?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipod

In my application, I want to copy a song from iPod Library.

How can I do that?

Comment: I read a very lengthy article detailing how to do this.  Summary was that you really, *really* want to avoid it.  I'll try to dig it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**.  It is possible, but hardly practical, to access raw song data.  What you do from there is up to you.  Here is a lengthy and detailed description of the process: http://www.subfurther.com/blog/?p=1103.

**EDIT:** Please be aware of App Store guideline 9.1 before making use of this technique.  These guidelines require a developer login, so I've removed them from my post.

Comment: You're very welcome.  If you're willing to share, I'd like to know why you find this necessary.  There may be an easier way to achieve your goal.

Comment: I have created one iPhone application to record voice with some music. I am having some default music in app resource. When I try to record with default music, It is playing good. When I try to record with any one song from iPod library, it is playing with some delay. So I decided to copy the song from iPod library. Then it will work.

Comment: Please note that this may get your app rejected from the store.  I hadn't realized when I posted my response.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't.
Apple should not allow this !

Edit : see [iPod Library Access Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) but I don't think you can access to file. Just metadata.

Comment: Is it possible in jailbreak device ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure SharePod does this, as well as a few other applications.  Definitely not impossible (I'm reading here that he wants to copy a song from the iPod to the computer.)

Comment: I want to copy a song from ipod to my iPhone application. Not to the computer.

Answer (score 0):

if iMovie can do it, and they say it is done with all public API's they are in direct conflict with themselves...

Maybe this gives them wiggle room to allow you to post iPod library content to YouTube, since YouTube handles the appropriate detection of sensitive audio. This is sticky but here is the final solution you should learn from to do the job...[iPodLibrary Music to PCM Samples revised](http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2010/12/13/from-ipod-library-to-pcm-samples-in-far-fewer-steps-than-were-previously-necessary/)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this it will helps you
 https://github.com/davidcairns/MediaPlayerDemo